# Interpreting tobit coefficients of 0

Tags: censoring, tobit-regression

I'm using a tobit model for a left censored dataset in R, and including both continuous and categorical predictor variables.  I've converted the factors to indicator coding for each level.  I was initially getting errors when trying to run a summary of the model output, which I discovered was due to the fact that some levels of the categorical variables have a coefficient of 0, even though there are observations for those levels.  I'm setting a reference level for the category using the level with the most observations.

I can't seem to find anything about why this would be happening.  This isn't survival regression where 0 coefficient is a soft model selection, is it?

If it is a form of model selection, how do I handle that given the factor itself?  I know in ridge regression I could use a form of grouping to test the variable overall.  Could I use a similar approach here?

Answer (score 1):

The betas at zero were appearing only when using the {AER} Tobit function.  Using the {VGAM} package with the vglm function returned values for the previously missing coefficients.  I'm assuming this is a problem with some levels of the categorical variables only having a few observations.  Combining those levels with others when creating the indicator variables fixed all problems with the models.